# JQuery code that worked in Chrome 59 now breaks in Chrome 60

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I had this config before Chrome update (Chrome/59.0.3071.112 V8/ 5.9.211.38) and now I have this one after Chrome update: Chorme/60.0.3112.90 V8 6.0.286.52.

The following code worked fine in Chrome 59 and now it breaks on Chrome 60. Can you please give me some advice? It looks like the find("Mensagem") method is not working anymore...

```js
$(function() {
  var retorno = $.parseXML('<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><op_st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00Response xmlns="http://www.capemisa.com.br/COB/st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00/2017/01"><op_st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00Result i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/><pProcedureRaiseErrorCollection xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Capemisa.WCFService.Core" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:ProcedureRaiseError><a:Fonte>.Net SqlClient Data Provider</a:Fonte><a:Mensagem>COB.st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00: A data de vencimento informada não é válida ou não foi possível verificar.</a:Mensagem><a:Numero>50000</a:Numero><a:NumeroLinha>105</a:NumeroLinha><a:Procedure>st_MensagemErro_Negocio_R_H00</a:Procedure><a:Servidor>RJOPVSQLD01\RJODBD02</a:Servidor></a:ProcedureRaiseError></pProcedureRaiseErrorCollection></op_st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00Response></s:Body></s:Envelope>');
  retorno = $(retorno);
  var dadosRetornoSucesso = retorno.find('op_st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00Result');
  var dadosRetornoErro = retorno.find('pProcedureRaiseErrorCollection');
  var mensagensErro = [];

  if (dadosRetornoErro.children().length > 0) {
    $.each(dadosRetornoErro.children(), function(i, msg) {
      console.log($(msg).find("Mensagem").text());
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "breaking"? What do you see in your browser's console?

Comment: Hi, Terry, that is the point. Before the update, the conosle.log() printed "COB.st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00: A data de vencimento informada não é válida ou não foi possível verificar." - the "Mensagem" content. After the update, it returns an empty string...

Comment: I'm not sure why the hate - but this is an interesting and relatively isolated question about a non-obvious to debug problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to select the tag in it's entirety: `a:Mensagem` instead of `Mensagem`. Also, you will need to escape the colon, so your selector should be `a\\:Mensagem`, i.e.:

```
$(msg).find('a\\:Mensagem').text()
```

I suspect that this is likely due to a bug with selectors in jQuery, because doing this works:

```
msg.querySelector('Mensagem').textContent
```

p/s: On a side note, I would discourage to use of `$.each()`. Instead, you should be passing a jQuery collection to `.each()` instead:

```
dadosRetornoErro.children().each(function(i) {
  console.log($(this).find('a\\:Mensagem').text());
});
```

... or, if you insist on using namespace selectors, you will have to use native JS ;)

```
dadosRetornoErro.children().each(function(i) {
  console.log(this.querySelector('Mensagem').textContent);
});
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
$(function() {
  var retorno = $.parseXML('<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><op_st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00Response xmlns="http://www.capemisa.com.br/COB/st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00/2017/01"><op_st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00Result i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/><pProcedureRaiseErrorCollection xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Capemisa.WCFService.Core" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:ProcedureRaiseError><a:Fonte>.Net SqlClient Data Provider</a:Fonte><a:Mensagem>COB.st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00: A data de vencimento informada não é válida ou não foi possível verificar.</a:Mensagem><a:Numero>50000</a:Numero><a:NumeroLinha>105</a:NumeroLinha><a:Procedure>st_MensagemErro_Negocio_R_H00</a:Procedure><a:Servidor>RJOPVSQLD01\RJODBD02</a:Servidor></a:ProcedureRaiseError></pProcedureRaiseErrorCollection></op_st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00Response></s:Body></s:Envelope>');
  retorno = $(retorno);
  var dadosRetornoSucesso = retorno.find('op_st_GerarBoletoCobranca_R_H00Result');
  var dadosRetornoErro = retorno.find('pProcedureRaiseErrorCollection');
  var mensagensErro = [];

  if (dadosRetornoErro.children().length > 0) {
    dadosRetornoErro.children().each(function(i) {
      console.log($(this).find('a\\:Mensagem').text());
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any chance you can find the commit that broke it? I'm curious

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I actually have no idea :) it seems to be an issue with jQuery's implementation of selectors tho, because `this.querySelector('Mensagem').textContent` actually works.

Comment: Please be sure to report this problem upstream to jQuery - the reason the web platform is stable is because people report these issues on :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum This feature appears to be broken in other browsers, and it can be reproduce with all versions of jQuery (v1.x, 2.x and 3.x). I believe that at this point, this should be a feature request instead?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, issue reported at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3750. Thanks!